# Random unable to connect from Azure to On-Premise MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, azure

We are using different services in the Azure Cloud (App services / function apps) to connect to a On-Premise MySql database on Ubuntu. This works the most time very well, but sometimes and totally random we received the following error.

**Detail:**

The connection works most time great and everything seems correct configured. Only sometimes e.g. every 27th request runs into an error. I assume the received error message is maybe wrong.

**Example extract from our log:**

```
2018-02-21 15:53:55.647 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection: An error occurred using the connection to database 'XXXXXXX' on server 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.<ConnectAsync>d__56.MoveNext() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 212
```

We are connecting to this database from different sites, but this error only appears from the Azure Cloud.
We double-checked the connection string, firewall settings and outgoing IPs several times.

**Connection String:**

```
Persist Security Info=True;server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;database=xxxxxx;uid=xxxxx;password=xxxxx;port=3306;
```

On some days we doesn’t received this error, but on the other day many times per day and totally random. It would be great to get help from you to identify the problem and solve it soon. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like azure cannot connect, despite you can. Maybe your ip is rejected because of missing ssl certificate, or your server is not reachanble from zure of any other reasons

Comment: I think you should ask about this error Azure Support team. It is more of their responsibility

Comment: The server is reachable for other applications and from other sites and also the most time from Azure. The IP, certificates, connection string and firewall should correct configured. Just sometimes it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that your server does not go down after many connections?

Comment: Yes, because all other application / connections are working fine and the next try to connect from Azure also. Just some single requests from Azure can't reach the database.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to help without a code example.
You can only check the common things:
- connection string correct order
 "Server=TheServerAddress; Port=YourPortNumber; Database=YourDatabase; Uid=YourUsername; Pwd=YourPassword;"
- add default port. Ex.: 3306 to connection string
- check the query code async or not and if its the same in other application

Also you can try a retry:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartr/2010/06/20/sql-azure-connection-retry-update/ 
 http://peterkellner.net/2011/01/21/sqlazure-connection-retry-problem-using-best-practices/

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. This helps to find a workaround. We had also the idea to implement several attempts and we will do that for safety reasons, but it would also be good to understand why the requests sometimes don't get through.

Comment: They `why` must probably be answered by the azure support team